# kde login screen only on 1 monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde-plasma-5, sddm

I'd like my kde login screen to be ONLY on 1 monitor. The other one is not always ON, and in that case I'm missing cursor and it's just inconvenient to use.

I learned, that kde uses `sddm`, learned about file `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`, and put there:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off --output DVI-D-1 --mode 1920x1200 --rate 59.95
```

which is command, that works after login. If I have both screens on, this will shutdown hdmi output, and keep only dvi. I cannot find any issue regarding `xrandr` in `journalctl`

Can anyone suggest what can be wrong? Is it possible that indices of HDMI are different while sddm is invoked? Or what can be the issue?